# Difference in efficiency between pickle and numpy.save()/numpy.savez() in saving numpy arrays?

Tags: arrays, performance, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to store exceptionally large numpy arrays. These are very large data sets, which even when broken up reach billions of elements.

What is the difference in terms of storage and speed between `pickle`/`cPickle` for Python3.x/Python2.7 and `numpy.save()`/`numpy.savez()`?

Are there any statistics or noticeable differences in the source code which sheds light on the differences in terms of efficiency?